# Tensor' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

when I using tensorflow with jupyter,I meet with a error:

```
img_h,img_w,img_c=128,384,3
I_t0,I_t1,learning_rate,steering=model_input(img_h,img_w,img_c)
assert I_t0.shape.as_list()==[None,128,384,3]
assert I_t1.shape.as_list()==[None,128,384,3]
assert steering.shape.as_list()==[None,1]
```

the error is

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-36e96cd24088> in <module>()
      1 img_h,img_w,img_c=128,384,3
      2 I_t0,I_t1,learning_rate,steering=model_input(img_h,img_w,img_c)
----> 3 assert I_t0.shape.as_list()==[None,128,384,3]
      4 assert I_t1.shape.as_list()==[None,128,384,3]
      5 assert steering.shape.as_list()==[None,1]

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

my tensorflow is 0.12.I don't know how to fix it Any wrong with my version of tensorflow?

Answer (score 2):

The tensor objects do not have a `shape` attribute in TensorFlow 0.12. (It was added in TensorFlow 1.0.)

You have to call the `get_shape` function:

```
I_t0.get_shape()
```